# how to run command in docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: php, laravel, docker

i have laravel project and i want to create docker for it
and i want to automation it
i want to run this commends:
{
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate
php artisan queue:work --daemon
}
and its my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: xxxx/lumen:Library
    container_name: Library
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: LibraryWebserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: Librarydb
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: library
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Library!23
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: Library!23
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

i try to use command: `php artisan migrate` and its do nothing
and also use 
command: `bash -c "php artisan migrate"`
command: `'php artisan migrate'`

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command

Comment: @eitank i want some one explain for me and say how to use commends

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `command` like the below example. It will run the command once the container is up and running.

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  app:
    image: busybox
    command: top
    networks:
      app_net:
        link_local_ips:
          - 57.123.22.11
```

Comment: when im use ```command : php artisan queue:work --daemon``` its return 502 error from ngin x

Comment: You should check if image has php installed in it.

Comment: @sushig can u help me for that?

Comment: you can use `docker exec -it <container_id> bash|sh`

Comment: @sushig its must like this:
``` command: docker exec -it app bash | php artisan queue:work```

Comment: sorry, it's not pipe | , It's / (or)